# PHP Attribute for innerhtml

Tags: php, getattribute

Is there any way to select the innerHTML via getAttribute in PHP.
I tried this already but it isn't working:

```
$fetchresult[] = array($link->getAttribute("innerhtml"), $link->nodeValue);
```

when i var_dump `$link` this is the output:

```
object(DOMElement)#7 (18) { ["tagName"]=> string(3) "div" 
["schemaTypeInfo"]=> NULL ["nodeName"]=> string(3) "div" ["nodeValue"]=> 
string(24) "TEXT" ["nodeType"]=> int(1) ["parentNode"]=> 
string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object 
value omitted)" ["firstChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
["lastChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["previousSibling"]=> NULL 
["nextSibling"]=> NULL ["attributes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
["ownerDocument"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["namespaceURI"]=> 
NULL ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["localName"]=> string(3) "div" ["baseURI"]=> NULL 
["textContent"]=> string(24) "TEXT" }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `innerHTML` is not an attribute.

Comment: what is `$link`? Post the full code.

Comment: `$link` is some html code

Comment: try `$link->textContent`. Maybe it'll work.

Comment: Since you haven't provided a [mcve], and didn't really answer the question of what kind of object `$link` is, I have guessed that you are using the DOM, in which case this question is a duplicate. If that is not the case, you will need to [edit] your question to provide enough information for someone to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerHTML` is not an attribute, it's a non-standard DOM extension that serializes (when used as a getter) the child nodes of the element to a string of HTML.

Going purely from reading the PHP manual, the equivalent would appear to be:

1. Create an empty string in a variable (`$html = ""`);
2. Loop over [childNodes](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes)
3. Append the HTML of that node to the variable (`$html .= $Node->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $Node );`)